# What is the meaning of 'softening process'?

Tags: gaussian-process

I do encounter the following terms in a number of academic journal papers:

> "For a **softening process**,
>   the third order Hermite functional transformation is ..."

[Efficient stationary multivariate non-Gaussian simulation based on a Hermite PDF model](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.probengmech.2015.09.006)

Similarly, for instance, the following:

> "This study presents a moment-based
>   translation model for **hardening** non-Gaussian processes with kurtosis less than three."

[Moment-Based Translation Model for Hardening Non-Gaussian Response Processes](http://ascelibrary.org/doi/10.1061/%28ASCE%29EM.1943-7889.0000986)

What do **softening**/**hardening** a process mean?

Answer (score 2):

Another journal paper seems to explain the terms:

> "Based on whether kurtosis is larger than 3, the *non-Gaussian
>   process* is classified as **“hardening”** (kurtosis<3) and **“softening”**
>   (kurtosis>3) cases"

[Revisiting moment-based characterization for wind pressures](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jweia.2016.02.006)